# Haskell - Determine what data type constructor was used in an if-then-else expression

Tags: haskell

I have the following code:

```
data Instruction = IntDec String String | Stop

run :: Instruction -> Bool
run inst = 
    if (isStop inst) then True
    else False
    where
        isStop :: Instruction -> Bool
        isStop (Stop) = True
        isStop _ = False
```

My question is is there a way to do the same code in the if statement. e.g.

```
run inst = 
        if (isTypeOf inst == Stop) then True
        else False
```

I know I could have simplified my code a lot by using this:

```
run Stop = True
run _ = False
```

but I want to use a if statement due to my actual code being a lot longer and complex

Comment: Pattern matching simplifies things. Guards are clear and clean. Try to avoid lots of intertwined if statements, because if statements are better kept for small subexpressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy for your particular case:

```
data Instruction = IntDec String String | Stop
                 deriving Eq

run :: Instruction -> Bool
run inst = inst == Stop
```

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't (short of comparing your value to a fully constructed instance... which only works if your values are actually `Eq`able).

What you *can* do is either write that function yourself, or use a case statement:

```
case aValue of
   Constructor x -> something
   Konstruktor y -> somethingElse
```

Unrelated note:

> I want to use a if statement due to my actual code being a lot longer and complex

This indicates that your code is likely *too* complex and that you should probably break it up into smaller functions. Doing too much in a single function makes writing it hard, and reading it later on nigh impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own query functions. For example, in `Data.Maybe` there are two functions defined:

```
isJust :: Maybe a -> Bool
isJust Just{}  = True
isJust _        = False

isNothing :: Maybe a -> Bool
isNothing Nothing = True
isNothing _       = False
```

and then use `isJust` and `isNothing` in your if statement.

Note the syntax in the `isJust` definition - `Just{}` is the same as `(Just _)` and the `{}` syntax is useful when a constructor has many arguments and you don't care about any of them.